# A page loads completely and refresh unexpectely

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am automating a webpage using selenium webdriver, when I navigate to such page one button keeps loading and when I check that the document.readystatus is complete and I click on the button then a small form opens but looks like the page refreshes and the form closes and I can not proceed with the workflow and fill the form. How can I ensure that the page is really ready to proceed

I tried to check that the page status is complete and the button is visible and clickable but that did not workout

Comment: Is the url public?